# When will HTML forms be able to use PUT and DELETE methods?

Tags: html, crud, w3c

After having been discussed almost 2 years ago and marked WONTFIX(1), now it seems to be in the process of finally getting fixed(2).

Does anybody know when this will finally get added to major browsers? (more close to "in a month" or more close to "in a year"?)

Especially bad is that both Chrome and Firefox not only ignore PUT and DELETE, but send a GET request in its place, exposing all the form variables in the URI.

- (1) https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=10671
- (2) https://www.w3.org/html/wg/tracker/issues/196

Comment: Q: Who cares?  You can use "put" and "delete" to your heart's content with most web servers, just about any Javascript client, and/or just about any Http client library.  What URL would an end-user want to access via a browser that isn't already covered under the standard "get" or "form/method=post" protocols?

Comment: An URL to delete or update something, as in DELETE or PUT. DELETE /profile or PUT /profile for example, as opposed to GET /profile. HTTP has that vocabulary for a reason. I know that I can send it via JS, but not every user may have JS enabled, and the GET fallback is not helpful.

Comment: [StackOverflow hasn't found a crystal ball yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131257/172661). :-) We can't predict the future, and this is not a discussion board. This question is 100% inappropriate for StackOverflow. Voting to close as "not constructive". Please review the [FAQ}(http://stackoverflow.com/faq) so you'll know what is (and is not) proper to ask here. Staying on-topic helps keep down clutter and makes SO a useful programming resource. Thanks.

Comment: Somebody may have more insight on the issue than I have, no "crystal ball" needed. It is constructive, because it helps me (and others) to decide wheather to implement a work-around or just wait a week or two.

Comment: @ChristianSteimel "wait a week or two"? are you kidding? it's more like "wait a year or two for the decision (if any) to sink to major browser manufacturers and then wait another year or two until the older browsers get into void"

Comment: Was that a guess or knowledge? In the past few years, stuff usually got into Chrome and FF only weeks after becoming W3C sanctioned, often even before it past W3C. What you are saying sounds more like 2005 than today. May I ask why so many people without actual knowledge on the issue are writing comments?

Comment: @ChristianSteimel css3 support by browsers: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html and the spec has been around for how long? ; now, let me remind you that MSIE7 is still widely used on market, despite MSIE9 being pushed as security update... so how far away are we from getting new form features? you tell me

Comment: I can tell you for sure it's not in the upcoming IE 10 ;)